# Pass value to another Activity by using getExtra

Tags: java, android

Having problem passing value to second activity page.

**First activity** able to toast and show the value of pname

```
Intent purchase = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PurchaseActivity.class);                  
startActivity(purchase);
purchase.putExtra("productname", pname.getText().toString());
finish();
```

**Second activity** not able to retrieve getStringExtra

```
    TextView test;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.purchase);

    test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textpurchaseitem);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    test.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("productname"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your first activity like this:

```
Intent purchase = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PurchaseActivity.class);
purchase.putExtra("productname", pname.getText().toString());                  
startActivity(purchase);

finish();
```

Comment: Thank you very much im too careless

Answer (score 1):

You should write below line before `startActivity`.

```
purchase.putExtra("productname", pname.getText().toString());
```

You wrote after `startActivity` so it not send your value to another activity because your data not append to your intent. So you need to call before `startActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

`startactivity` should be below `putextra` so that values can be passed from first activity to other

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution

```
Intent purchase = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PurchaseActivity.class);

purchase.putExtra("productname", pname.getText().toString());
startActivity(purchase);

finish();

Intent intent = getIntent();
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("productname")!=null)
    test.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("productname"));
```